# Как рекурсивно перевернуть список?

Tags: python, рекурсия, список

Как используя рекурсию можно перевернуть список?

Comment: Можно. Пробуйте.

Answer (score 3):

А чего скромничать, давайте сразу чистую функцию без изменяемых переменных

```
def rev(array):
    if not array:
        return []
    return [array[-1]] + rev(array[:-1])
```

(Правда, в питоне такой подход скорее всего будет жутко тормозить)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
s_new = []

def reverse(s):
  if len(s)==1:
    s_new.append(s[0])
    return 
  s_new.append(s[-1])
  return reverse(s[0:len(s)-1])

reverse(s)

print(s_new)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Глобальная переменная это не круто

Answer (score 0):

Использовать: `list.reverse()`

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: А где рекурсия?

Comment: @Эникейщик, а вот словосочетание "используя рекурсию" я упустил когда прочитал вопрос. Да и вообще нужно не изобретать свои костыли.

Comment: Да обычная домашка. Там и не такое изобретают :)

Comment: @Эникейщик, ух, мне бы домашку на питоне, а не на скале и окемле))

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []


def recursive_reverse(some_list):
    global a
    if some_list == []:
        return a
    else:
        a.append(some_list[-1])
        return recursive_reverse(some_list[:-1])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Чистая рекурсивная функция с аргументом-аккумулятором:

```
def rev(array, result=None):    
    if not array:
        return result

    if result is None:
        result = []

    result.append(array[-1])
    return rev(array[:-1], result)
```